# Android Studio - Implement library

Tags: java, android, maven, android-studio

How can I import this library? https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView/ 
I don't get it, I'm not familiar with Maven and all this stuff.
Thank you!

Comment: What build system/IDE are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's clearly listed on the github readme to add the dependency to your build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.ksoichiro:android-observablescrollview:1.3.1'
}
```

Comment: Which build.gradle? And also, there is written: 
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
But I don't have that, I just find: 
repositories {
    jcenter()
}

Comment: the one in your `app` folder

Comment: if you don't have mavenCentral repo, then add that as well